# What is the justification for taking the parameter $u$ as the arc length $s$?

Tags: calculus, vectors

Let a curve be defined by the parametric equations $x=f(u)$ and $y=g(u)$

The derivative of the position vector **r**(u) is (dx/du)**i** + (dy/du)**j** = d**r**/du & is a vector of magnitude $\sqrt((dx/du)^2+(dy/du)^2)$= ds/du

Let s denote the arc length measured from a fixed point $P_0$ of the curve so that s increases with u. If the scalar variable u is taken to be the arc length s, then equation the becomes **t** = d**r**/ds = dx/ds **i** + dy/ds **j** The magnitude of **t** is $\sqrt((dx/ds)^2 + (dy/ds)^2))$ = 1

In this demonstration they take the parameter u as the arc length s. What is the justification for replacing u and the differential du in both equations with s and ds? Considering the arc length s is dependent on u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When arc length is the parameter the speed of curve traversal is constant. Only the direction changes. That makes analyzing the curve easier. The second derivative will be normal to the curve and tell you how fast it's bending.